# parseTime and functions in D3 have errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am currently learning D3, following a tutorial.

I have an error "d3.timeParse is not a function" on the first line in the main.js file. Also when I remove the variables parseTime and formatTime, I get the error ".then(function(data) is not a function"

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is the main.js file -

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d/%m/%Y");

d3.json("data/calls.json").then(function(data){    

    data.map(function(d){
        d.call_revenue = +d.call_revenue
        d.units_sold = +d.units_sold
        d.call_duration = +d.call_duration
        d.date = parseTime(d.date)
        return d
    })

    allCalls = data;

    calls = data;

    nestedCalls = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){
            return d.category;
        })
        .entries(calls)

    donut = new DonutChart("#company-size")

    revenueBar = new BarChart("#revenue", "call_revenue", "Average call revenue (USD)")
    durationBar = new BarChart("#call-duration", "call_duration", "Average call duration (seconds)")
    unitBar = new BarChart("#units-sold", "units_sold", "Units sold per call")

    stackedArea = new StackedAreaChart("#stacked-area")

    timeline = new Timeline("#timeline")

    $("#var-select").on("change", function(){
        stackedArea.wrangleData();
    })
})



function brushed() {
    var selection = d3.event.selection || timeline.x.range();
    var newValues = selection.map(timeline.x.invert)
    changeDates(newValues)
}

function changeDates(values) {
    calls = allCalls.filter(function(d){
        return ((d.date > values[0]) && (d.date < values[1]))
    })

    nestedCalls = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){
            return d.category;
        })
        .entries(calls)

    $("#dateLabel1").text(formatTime(values[0]))
    $("#dateLabel2").text(formatTime(values[1]))

    donut.wrangleData();
    revenueBar.wrangleData();
    unitBar.wrangleData();
    durationBar.wrangleData();
    stackedArea.wrangleData();
}
```

This is the index.html file -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Corporate Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/dc.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src=""></a>      
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="left-charts" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Dates: <span id="dateLabel1">01/01/2017</span> - <span id="dateLabel2">10/12/2017</span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select id="var-select" class="form-control">
                            <option selected value="call_revenue">Revenue (USD)</option>
                            <option value="call_duration">Call Time (seconds)</option>
                            <option value="units_sold">Units Sold</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>                          
                </div>
                <div id="stacked-area"></div>
                <div id="timeline"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="right-charts" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12" id="company-size"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12" id="units-sold"></div>                    
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12" id="revenue"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12" id="call-duration"></div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<!-- External JS Libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/dc.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/queue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/barChart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/main.js"></script>


</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably include the d3 library. Add this to the beginning.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Here is the whole documentation to the library, check it out: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki

Comment: Thank you, although I do include d3 locally using the d3 file

Comment: Maybe you are not including it correctly or the path could be wrong. If you open the browser console (F12) are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes the only error I have in the console is - Uncaught TypeError: d3.timeParse is not a function at main.js:3

Comment: I'm sure that the path for including is incorrect somewhere. I've tested the d3 library and it works fine. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/frmw8u1q/

Comment: Ok, so I removed the link to the d3.min file and added the d3 http link above and it now works :) thank you ziga1337!